# Mobilefirst 8.0 Inconsistent behaviour when trying to obtain security context in JAXRS filter

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to obtain the adapter security context to get the current logged in user in my api filter. However it seems like the behaviour after each adapter deployment is random and inconsistent. Sometimes after adapter deployment i will be able to obtain the user but sometimes i will only get a null value as the user although there has been no code changes.

I have also tried changing the priority of the filter but nothing seems to work consistently.

I using Mobilefirst 8.0 with spring framework

My filter looks something like this

```
@Provider
public class ApiFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Context
    AdapterSecurityContext securityContext;

    @Context
    ConfigurationAPI configApi;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String username = currentUser.getId();
            logger.debug("Username: " + username);
        } else {
            logger.debug("User not logged in");
        }
    }
}
```

This is a snippet of my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean
    class="com.github.mfpdev.adapters.spring.integration.JAXRSResourcesRegistryImpl">
    <property name="resources">
        <list>
            <bean name="apiFilter" class="com.api.ApiFilter" />
            <bean class="com.api.controller.DefaultController" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your complete project? when you say for certain adapters it works and for certain it does nt...is it consistently working for the adapters where it work? <ie> if you deploy/redeploy the same adapter, do u get the id logged properly? Also can you clarify if you are using  a specific JAXRS Implementation foryour filter?

Comment: Are you using the filter inside of the adapter itself as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352998/how-to-write-global-filter-for-mobilefirst-8-0-java-adapter ?

Comment: What i meant was that i am actually deploying the same adapter, via the command `mvn clean install adapter:deploy` and for every deployment, i may or may not be able to get the security context in my filter. For example, in the first deployment, the filter works perfectly, however when i deploy it again, i will get a null user although i have made zero changes in the code.

Comment: Have you written the filter as global filter / as filter with in the adapter?

Comment: Where/how do I define whether it is a global filter?